# Add SSL to a domain which is hosted from the same directory as another domain on nginx

Tags: https, security-certificate

I have a sub domain for eg `subdomain.maindomainA.example` which is pointing to `subdomain.maindomainB.example` [SSL enabled].  The A record of `subdomain.maindomainA.com` points to the IP address of `subdomain.maindomainB.com` so the two subdomains are serving the same content.

Would it be possible to make `subdomain.maindomainA.example` SSL enabled if yes then what common name would be provided while generating CSR.

Comment: Even if the DNS is pointing to the same IP, you can configure the server to redirect one to the other if you want to.

Comment: First, don't use common name but use subject alternative name. Then, the name in the certificate must match the name in the URL used. In this case this means the name how the site gets accessed initially and not the name where it is redirecting to.

Comment: You should be able to provide multiple domains when making the certificate.  Give it both subdomain.maindomainA.com and subdomain.maindomainB.com.  Configuration is going to be different depending on how you are doing these things. Are you using Apache? Nginx?  You need to provide more details to get better help.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch I am using Nginx.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an HTTP redirection from one URL to another, the browser has to connect to first URL, negotiate TLS if using HTTPS, and then only get back answer from the webserver with a `location` header to learn the new URL.

Which means in turn that if the browser has to contact the first URL it needs to compelete the TLS handshake fully hence it needs an appropriate certificate received from this host, with the hostname in this first URL.

Then if it gets a redirect to a new HTTPS URL it will again conduct TLS handshake for this new host and hence it will need to receive (typically) another certificate with this new hostname in it.

There are various ways to handle this situation certificate wise:

- you have two completely separate certificates, each one with one name
- if both names have something in common (something longer than a TLD), then you may use only one "wildcard" certificate, like one for `*.example.com` would allow the first URL to be `https://landing.example.com/` and second URL be `https://finaldestination.example.com/`
- or you can also have one certificate listing both names, even if completely different, as long as you are able to prove to the CA you control both names at certificate issuance. This is using the "Subject Alternative Names" extension.

Comment: Thank you. I think option 3 will be more appropriate. For option 1 I think they need to put their domain name as common name? I don't have access to their domain name settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nginx, you could do something like this:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;

  include /etc/nginx/ssl-stuff.common;

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

And

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  include /etc/nginx/ssl-stuff.common;

  root /var/www/html;
}
```

With ssl-stuff.common containing:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/somename/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/somename/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```

Just make sure you request both of the domains when you create the certificate.

Comment: That seems like a lot more work than getting a SAN certificate that covers multiple host names.   They didn't mention that they were using nginx, so specific configuration for it probably won't be helpful.   They also may have a hosting company and don't have root access.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's not really a lot of work either way. They mentioned it in the comments.  Just trying to help as best I can with the little information given.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen that they mentioned nginx.  +1 then.

Comment: Thanks @RaisinBranCrunch. The problem is that the other sub domain is hosted by a third party and I do not have access to that sub domain which is  `subdomain.maindomainA.example`. The A record of that sub domain points to my sub domain which is `subdomain.maindomainB.com`. Sorry I should have told you this before.

Comment: Except for specific reasons, you should not anymore run TLS1.0 or 1.1

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The value of ssl_protocols is currently the default for Nginx.  Leaving out TLS1.0 would unfortunately leave behind a small amount of users, and including it is normal.  It seems like TLS1.1 and 1.2 are disabled by default in IE 8, 9, and 10. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220586&language=en_US&type=1 The highest version of TLS will be prioritized for users, although a malicious user could manually force a downgrade to TLS1.0.  If security is more important than those IE users, TLS 1.0 definitely shouldn't be used.

Comment: Define "normal" in "and including it is normal.".  TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are deprecated and suffers various vulnerabilities hence various standards require/strongly suggest/mandate to use only TLS 1.2 or later. See PCI-DSS for example, Canadian government rules, or https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/06/19/ietf_calls_for_formal_tls_1_0_1_1_deprecation/ for what is being done at the IETF level. " although a malicious user could manually force a downgrade to TLS1.0" which is exactly why a server should not advertise it at all.  And see RFC7507 for mitigations against downgrade attacks

Comment: See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html for a good review of which clients can not speak 1.2 nowadays. So like I said, except if you have very solid reason to need to support a specific old client that you can not update, there are no good reasons to keep 1.0 or 1.1 (which is very seldom used anyway) activated today. Because otherwise you jeopardize ALL of your clients, including the ones that could have done 1.2 in fact.

Comment: IE 8 9 and 10 are Window 7/8 era browsers. They are EOL since long ago. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_version_history#OS_compatibility, version 9 is not supported since 2017. Version 10 was released in 2012.  Windows 7 is EOL on 2015, and 8 in 2018.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree with your philosophy wholeheartedly, but the reality is that, depending on the product, a significant portion of users are still using those old versions (2% and above) and if you tell your boss you want to stop supporting them, he will often say no. Yes, it is still common to see TLS 1.0, even on Amazon and Ebay, because profit defeats safety and IE has not finished haunting the Internet just yet.

Comment: Like I said at the beginning: "Except for specific reasons". IE: if you know you need to support some explicit customers with no other options, then it may be needed but then you should at least put safeguards in place so that you are 1.2 for everyone with no downgrade possible, and then a specific channel for specific customers that can not meet that. If you blindly put 1.0 everywhere you jeopardize all your customers and I am sure your boss will not be keen to have customers coming back to him telling him they were robed by some attackers tricking them to another website than your legitimate

Comment: On Amazon/Ebay:note that they both use TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV to limit downgrade attacks. Also note that they are tricks, like CloudFlare does, for the server to change its reply at beginning of the TLS handshake based on what the client sends.The list of supported ciphers can sometimes be a good indication of which versions are supported,and the server could do only 1.2 by default but present 1.0 only to specific clients exhibiting specific behavior.Which is safer than 1.0 for anyone.I expect these companies to have the knowledge to do the bad 1.0 in a secure way, but maybe not any small business?

Comment: Please provide sources for "Yes, it is still common to see TLS 1.0" eventually. https://github.com/sftcd/tls-oldversions-diediedie/blob/master/draft-moriarty-tls-oldversions-diediedie-01.txt shows some recent statistics but then it all depends how you translate "common" to numbers :-)